# Launched new instance on EC2 with same keypair, can't ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

This is on AWS. I tried to launch a new Ubuntu instance (#2) with the same keypair that is associated with another Ubuntu instance (#1).

AWS instances are associated with keypairs at the time they are launched and cannot be changed once launched.

I can connect to instance #1 but can't connect to instance #2 using the same ssh command. I've checked my permissions and everything seems to be ok.

The key is in ~/AMI.pem.

I have chmod 600 on my home directory and chmod 400 on ~/AMI.pem, so it's only readable/writeable by me.

The instances are nearly identical, with the same security groups and keypairs, same version of Ubuntu, etc. Instance #1 has some additional packages installed. I verified both are associated with the same keypair called "AMI".

Connecting to #2:

```
USAU9900:ScrapeEdgar reedn$ ssh -i ~/AMI.pem -v ubuntu@54.67.18.96
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/reedn/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.67.18.96 [54.67.18.96] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/reedn/AMI.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reedn/AMI.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 36:69:f6:95:b4:3c:f0:77:02:ab:02:01:af:c7:cc:6a
debug1: Host '54.67.18.96' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/reedn/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/reedn/AMI.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
*Permission denied (publickey).*
```

Connecting to instance #1:

```
USAU9900:ScrapeEdgar reedn$ ssh -i ~/AMI.pem -v ubuntu@54.183.77.100
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/reedn/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.183.77.100 [54.183.77.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/reedn/AMI.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/reedn/AMI.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA a6:53:a0:99:b8:61:ef:fe:05:d3:fe:47:90:ea:de:b6
The authenticity of host '54.183.77.100 (54.183.77.100)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is a6:53:a0:99:b8:61:ef:fe:05:d3:fe:47:90:ea:de:b6.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '54.183.77.100' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/reedn/AMI.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 54.183.77.100 ([54.183.77.100]:22)
```

Comment: `debug1: Trying private key: /Users/reedn/AMI.pem...debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey` The client tried the key, and the server didn't accept it. You'll need to troubleshoot this on the server.

Comment: Since I can't ssh to the server, how can I troubleshoot?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear this is about an EC2 instance.

Comment: There are at least half a dozen things on the server that could cause this. This is an extremely common question, and it's not really on topic for stackoverflow. Your best bet is to search this site or http://superuser.com/ for "[ssh] Permission denied (publickey)".

Answer (score 0):

First you need make sure the keypair has been applied to instance #2. Something like below in aws console on this instance:

```
Key pair name: AMI (should be same as instance #1)
```

Then try below steps:

1. If this ec2 instance is not in VPC, could you stop and start the instance to refresh with new public IP address and try again?
2. clean content in .ssh/known_hosts in your local machine, and try again.

One of them should work for you.